# invalid column name 'infinity' (odbc c#)

Tags: c#, ssis, odbc

I have written a generic c# script task in ssis to take a salesforce table paramater, select the data from salesforce over odbc 32 bit driver, and insert the results into a DWH table in sqlserver using insert statements.

This has worked fine for most tables, but for a random table or so it generates the error "Invalid column name 'Infinity'".

Now i log the sql before I execute it, and it contains no reference to a column called Infinity.

I can run the ssis job manually (right click, execute) and it succeeds, its only when i execute with sp_start_job in a framework it fails, and fails at different row counts... (which may just be due to ordering from initial fetch, ie maybe there is some bad data, but again i log the sql before I execute and it succeeds when run manually)

I haven't attached any code, as I don't think this is related to a code error, but some odd bug in ssis/c#/odbc, just after general ideas where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

seems the way to solve this / prevent it is to put single quotes around all fields in the insert (ie i believe a float,double or some numeric field legit held an infinity value somehow and this quoting handled it)